# Solve $\sin(ax) / \sin(x) = a/2$ for $x$

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

I am currently trying to solve $\sin(ax)/\sin(x) = a/2$ for $x$, where $x$ is between $0$ and $\pi$ and $a$ is a constant.

As I have limited skills in math, I cannot seem to solve this problem without a brute force solution using Matlab to calculate a numerical value for this equation, I was wondering if there is a mathematical solution to this.

$a$ is non-zero, and around $500,000$ for my application.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: even within the interval $0 \le x \le \pi.$ wil have lots of solutions. in fact in each interval $2j\pi/a \le x \le (2j+1)\pi/a$ has two solutions.

Comment: Since $a$ is rather large, $x$ will have to be rather close to $0$ or $\pi$. This means it should be rather easy to get a very accurate numerical answer.

Comment: @abel Are you sure? Try looking at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%2820x%29%2Fsin%28x%29%3D10

Comment: That said, given that Wolfram Alpha is expressing its exact answers in terms of roots of polynomials that are not solvable by radicals, I don't think there is a nice closed form answer.

Comment: @Ian, yes i dropped the amplitude $a.$ that will change the number of roots.there is one in $0 \le x \le \pi/a.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always have the trivial solution $x=0$.

The next root is a small value (on the order of $1/a$), so that the sine is very well approximated by $x$ (the next term being $-x^3/6$). The equation is rewritten

$$\frac{\sin ax}{a\sin x}\approx\frac{\sin ax}{ax}=\text{sinc }ax=\frac12,$$
hence
$$x\approx\frac1a\text{sinc}^{-1}\frac12=\frac{1.895494267034\cdots}a$$

For large $a$ this initial approximation is excellent, if not just sufficient.

Then no other root is found until the end of the range, very close to $\pi$. Making the change of variable $\dfrac ta=\pi-x$, we can approximate the sine as $\dfrac ta$. The equation becomes

$$\sin(a\pi-t)\approx\frac t2.$$

By the periodicity of the sine, we can replace $a\pi$ by $b=a\pi\bmod 2\pi$, a more manageable coefficient.

Anyway, uness $a$ is integer, there is no further simplification here and the equation has the general form of the intersection of a straight line with a sinusoid, $\sin p=\alpha p+\beta$, that can have up to three solutions and needs to be solved numerically.

To get started, the two arches of the sinusoid can be approximated by $4p(\pi-p)/\pi^2$ and $-4(p-\pi)(2\pi-p)/\pi^2$, leading to quadratic equations.

UPDATE: numerical issue

Actually, finding the root(s) close to $\pi$ is an ill-posed problem. Indeed, its location depends on the value of $a\pi\bmod2\pi$ so that $a$ needs to be known with, say $2$ exact decimals ($8$ significant digits). If this is not the case, all you can say is that $|\dfrac t2|<1$ and $x$ is in the range $(\pi-2/a,\pi)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$y = ax$,
so
$\sin(ax)/\sin(x) = a/2$
becomes
$\sin(y)/\sin(y/a) = a/2$.

Since $a$ is large,
under the assumption that
$y/a$ is small,
I will approximate 
$\sin(y/a)$
by
$y/a$,
so this becomes
$a \sin(y)/y = a/2$
or
$\sin(y)/y = 1/2$.

The solution to this,
according to alphy,
is
$y \approx ±1.89549$,
so that
$x = y/a
\approx ±1.89549/a
$.